# Spark detecting screwdriver doesn't light up upon touching live wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, socket

For one outlet I'm working on, the tester screwdriver stopped lighting up, it used to before with same exact wires a few days ago, but now doesn't. I was cutting and replacing old wires whoch took some time but touching the old or new wires shows nothing.

The screwdriver works on every there outlet, it's Stanley and it says 100v - 500v AC. Here it's euro standard, where devices are rated 240V 10A. The outlet works, but I'm afraid I may have done something accidentally that let the outlet only output less than 100v, which is bad.

Comment: You say the outlet works on a 240 v line if the voltage was wired some way to get 100 v it really would not work.

Comment: If the tool doesn't light up, how do you know the point is energized?  If you plug a night-light in there, does it light? Is a digital voltmeter involved in any way?

Comment: The plug and all work, there is power. But the tester either emitts too faint of a light or none at all, kind of random. I don't understand the whole 240v, devices here need 240v and the tester range is 100v - 500v AC. Is the tool made only for American outlets? My  multimeter burnt from a bad socket or something which is why I'm changing them.